# How to create a email registration link in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a php registration form and a login form for users, when the user enters his id, he/she has to get a registration link to his email to the registration form using a token and id, the email has to be sent only if his/her id exists in the database, and when the user clicks the registration page the form should contain prefilled data like name and id and with few editable fields such as designation and date-of-birth, how do i acheive this since i am a newbie to php and mysql.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Create a random number and save it as a token in your database and send it along with the link in the email. Now when someone clicks that link from email, then you match that token in database and update the column with status verified and delete the token.Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate a random token form random numbers

   `$token =substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 15);`
2. Send that token with the link in email

   `<a href="www.example.com/register?token=ABC123">Registration Link</a>`
3. Store token in your database for future verification when user comes after clicking link
4. Match the token in the link with token in the database
5. Fetch the details of that user and prefill the form data
6. Update the user data and delete the token